# Очень простой скрипт удаления. Доработка

Tags: linux, bash

Есть скрипт удаления файлов в директориях, который берет переменные из друго файла.

delete.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. /file
find /users/$directory -mtime +$day -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

file

```
directory="test"
day="8"
```

Хочу его доработать, таким образом чтобы переменных было несколько `$directory1` `$day1` и тд. Подскажите как правильно создать условие, с учетом отсутствия или наличия этих самых директорий

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь правильно вас понял.

Начинаем с того, что директория у нас может быть только одна, поэтому переменную directory нужно проверять от случайного появления двойного пути типа `directory="test /root"` или на пустоту когда переменная `directory=""`.

```sh
. /file
#Защищаемся от пустоты в переменной, значение empty будет присвоено в случае если directory пуста
checkfolder() {
dir="${1:-'empty'}"
[[ $dir == empty ]] && {
printf "Каталог для поиска и удаления не задан\n"
return 1; }
```

#на несколько перечисленных адресов:

```sh
if [[ -n `grep -P '^[A-Za-z\/\.].*[ \t][\.\/]' <<< "${dir}"` ]]; then
    #Ключ -n подразумевает что сработает true если у команды будет вывод, используется по умолчанию, поэтому указывать не обязательно
    #далее команда grep с подключенными расширенными регулярными выражениями
    #^ - символ начала строки
    #[A-Za-z\/\.] - любая буква латинского алфавита, точка или слеш
    #.* - любая последовательность символов
    #[ \t] - пробел или табуляция
    #[\.\/] - точка или слеш
    #В итоге у нас получается, что если в переменной directory присутствует в тексте пробел или табуляция после чего будет символ "." или "/" сработает первый блок true.
    [[ ${3} == --force ]] && { printf "Пропускаем проверку для ${dir}\n"; } || {
    printf "параметры директории неявны\n"
    printf "убедитесь что в /file корректно задано имя каталога,\n"
    printf "если переменная задана верно, то запускайте меня --force\n"
    return 1; }
fi
```

#Теперь стандартные проверки переменных

```sh
if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
    #-d - это проверка на наличие директории
    #-f - наличие файла
    #-e - наличие элемента директории/файла
    printf "Директория $dir существует\n"
else
    printf "Директории $dir нет, выходим\n"
    return 2
fi

if [[ -n `sed 's/[0-9]//g' <<< "${2:-empty}"` ]]; then
    #sed убираем все цифры и если останется какой либо текст, то значит переменная не правильно объявлена, так же если переменная day пуста, зайдем сюда
    printf "Некорректно указано количество дней\n"
    return 3
fi
}
```

И далее можно переходить к удалению файлов и каталогов

```sh
#передаем функции директорию и дату, если все ок выполняем удаление
checkfolder "$directory" "$day" && {
#на время тестов заменил бы выполнение удаления на вывод файлов убрав -exec rm -rf {} \;
find /users/$directory -mtime +$day -exec rm -rf {} \;
}
checkfolder "$directory1" "$day1" && {
find /users/$directory1 -mtime +$day1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
}
checkfolder "$directory2" "$day2" && {
find /users/$directory2 -mtime +$day2 -exec rm -rf {} \;
}
```

---

А вообще если говорить о нескольких переменных, то рекомендовал бы воспользоваться массивом, к примеру в /file добавлять записи типа

```sh
directory[0]=dirname
day[0]=10
directory[1]=dirname2
day[1]=20
directory[2]=dirname3
day[2]=30
```

далее после объявления функции checkfolder в скрипте delete.sh создать перебор по записям в массиве

```sh
...
i=0
while [[ $i -lt ${#directory[@]} ]] do
checkfolder "${directory[$i]}" "${day[$i]}" && {
find /users/${directory[$i]} -mtime +${day[$i]} -exec rm -rf {} \;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы порекомендовал хранить в файле `file` не переменные, а просто текст:

```
8  test
16 path/to/test/dir/2
1  path/with space/
```

тогда исходный вариант можно просто обернуть в `while read` с перенаправлением потока:

```
while read day directory; do
  find "/users/$directory" -mtime "+$day" -exec rm -rf {} \;
done < file
```

**Замечания:**

- В bash разыменование всех переменных стоит оборачивать в двойные кавычки, если явно не требуется обратное.
- Комбинация `rm -rf` и `mtime` может дать неожиданный результат с деревом каталогов, так что я бы рекомендовал использовать что-то такого рода:

  ```
  find "/users/$directory" -mtime "+$day" ! -type d -exec rm -f '{}' +
  find "/users/$directory" -mtime "+$day" -type d -empty -exec rmdir '{}' +
  # ^ Пустые каталоги будут удаляться только после `day` дней.
  ```